# Zend Cache not working using Action Helper

Tags: php, zend-framework, caching, output-buffering

I'm trying to implement full page static caching in my Zend Framework application. Using the Static backend coupled with the Capture frontend, whole pages can be cached, and served by a .htaccess redirect in the future, until the cache is deleted/regenerated. For reference, I've been using the section on [Zend_Cache_Backend_Static](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.cache.backends.html) in the manual, and also some [further information](http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-9148?focusedCommentId=38409#action_38409) provided by the class author.

As per the example, I have configured the directories for the cache (static HTML files) and their tags, and I have added the line:

```
$this->_helper->cache(array('index'), array('allentries'));
```

to one of my controllers.

The HTML file is created in the correct place, and the tags are also created as expected. However, the HTMl file is always blank - 0 bytes.

I can't diagnose the problem, and I can't find any information online to help. As far as I can see it's some problem with the Output Buffering callback which receives the output from the Zend app, but I don't know precisely what's wrong.

Can anybody shed some light on the issue?

Comment: It seems as if the ob_start callback function is being passed an empty string every time. If I append the string 'test' to the data inside the Zend_Cache_Frontend_Capture::_flush method, only the string 'test' is written to the HTML file. Any idea why the callback isn't receiving the HTML contents of the generated page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of head scratching, I found the answer:

```
; required for page caching
resources.frontController.params.disableOutputBuffering = true
```

...in the application INI file.